# sqlException : column not found JPA @query

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm using @query annotation but when I try to fetch count of records it throws

```
java.sql.SQLException: Column 'allowPartialPay' not found.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1094) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.31.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:997) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.31.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:983) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.31.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:928) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.31.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.findColumn(ResultSetImpl.java:1162) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.31.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getBoolean(ResultSetImpl.java:1781) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.31.jar:na]
```

I'm writing my custom queries in repository.

InvoiceRepository.java

```
public interface InvoiceRepository extends JpaRepository<Invoice, Integer>{

    Invoice findByInvoiceNumber(String invoiceNumber);

    List<Invoice> findByUserId(int id);

    @Query(value = "select c.id,c.business_name,count(i.id) from client c join invoice i on c.id = i.client_id where i.date <= :agingDate group by c.id",nativeQuery=true)
    List<Invoice> findInvoiceCount(@Param("agingDate")Date agingDate);

}
```

ReportService.java

```
if(report.getReportBy().equals("invoiceCount")){
                    result = invoiceRepository.findInvoiceCount(report.getAgingDate());
                }
```

Invoice.java

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Invoice {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Client client;

    @Column
    private boolean allowPartialPay;
}
```

Database

[image]

Comment: @NeilStockton I've updated my repository code

Comment: it comes from invoice table and the query invoked is 'select c.id,c.business_name,count(i.id) from client c join invoice i on c.id = i.client_id where i.date <= ? group by c.id'

Comment: @NeilStockton also i've added service from which method is called

Comment: Since you are running a native query return `List<Object[]>` from your query method.

Answer (score 9):

It comes during mapping result set into java Invoice class (as you declared it as return type List for method findInvoiceCount() ). native query return in your case Object[] instead of List.

You can see it in log exception

> ResultSetImpl.findColumn(ResultSetImpl.java:1162

So it happens in result mapping stage ,after query has executed.

```
@Query(value = "select c.id,c.business_name,count(i.id) from client 
          c join invoice i on c.id = i.client_id 
           where i.date <= :agingDate group by c.id",nativeQuery=true)
    List<Invoice> findInvoiceCount(@Param("agingDate")Date agingDate);
```

spring data gets result set from query result and tries to map it into Invoice field by field (try to contruct Invoice class ). But actual type it's Object[].

If you need get some DTO as result your query , with fields like is result set : 'c.id,c.business_name,count(i.id)' use @SqlResultSetMapping (you can map result columns from select query into your dto). Or change return type from List  to Object[] and iterate it as you need.

Here is example for [Result Set Mapping: The Basics](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/result-set-mapping-basics/).

Answer (score 0):

Use, `nativeQuery=false`, because you have used the JQL query and not the SQL query. If you are using the SQL query, you can simply use the `nativeQuery=true`.